# How to create an intent with multiple slot values in its utterances in AWS Lex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlp, chatbot, amazon-lex, aws-lex

How do I create an intent which expects multiple consecutive slot values in its utterances which are set to expandable values? In the screenshot, the manufacturer model variant trio appears together in the utterances. Problem is the manufacturer and model slot types has possible two-three word values and variants could go up to five words. Lex is not able to understand the manufacturer utterances and straightaway detecting model slot type. How do I deal with this issue? Thanks.

[intent utterance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sToHN.jpg)   [test chat screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xDm4.jpg)  [slot data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkcVu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should greatly increase the values listed in your `manufacture` slotType so that it can better detect all the possibilities, especially since you need it to differentiate from the next slot.

Then also increase the variations of the intent utterances.

The error looks like the slotType is set to "Restrict to Slot values and Synonyms" so make sure you have it saved, built, and published with the setting "Expand Values" applied.

You should try to "teach" Lex as much as possible with all the expected variations of slotType values and utterances, but there will still be things that Lex will fail to catch. So I highly suggest using Lambda to parse the slot values, and sometimes the input itself so that you make sure the values are placed in the correct slots.